# Automating running of code snippet of Python in Azure server

Tags: python, azure

Is it possible to automate a code snippet with Python to be run for example every hour? If yes, how it is done?

This code is aimed to be run on Azure server.

Comment: windows scheduler or crontab is suitable for this kind of jobs

Comment: @VigneshKalai, thanks for that info. The aim is that the code should be run on server. Sorry that I forgot to add that into the question.

Comment: The Python interpreter is an executable, so you can schedule it to run at certain intervals or times the same way you would any other on your OS or within your environment.

Comment: @martineau thanks for your answer. It seems that since I need to run a code snippet on server, this is more server specific question.

Comment: With Azure, a [**Web Job**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Azure#WebJobs) "...can be deployed to a Web App to implement background processing. That can be invoked on a schedule, on demand or can run continuously".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According your comments, it seems that your application is hosted on Azure Web Apps. We can leverage web jobs to run background tasks on Azure Web Apps.
General steps,

1,Compress your python script into a zip file

2,login on [Azure management portal](https://manage.windowsazure.com/), click WEBJOBS tab in your website dashboard navigation.

3,Click Add to create a web job task, input a name, upload the zip file with your python script, and configure frequency of running the task.
[image]

For more information, please refer to [Run Background tasks with WebJobs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/) on official site.

Comment: Liu: Thanks for your answer. That solved the case :)